# Why does Keras halt at the first epoch when I attempt to train it using fit_generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Keras to fine tune an existing VGG16 model and am using a fit_generator to train the last 4 layers. Here's the relevant code that I'm working with:

```
# Create the model
model = models.Sequential()

# Add the vgg convolutional base model
model.add(vgg_conv)

# Add new layers
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

# Show a summary of the model. Check the number of trainable params
model.summary()
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

#Change the batchsize according to the system RAM
train_batchsize = 100
val_batchsize = 10

train_dir='training_data/train'
validation_dir='training_data/validation'

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(image_size1, image_size2),
    batch_size=train_batchsize,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_dir,
    target_size=(image_size1, image_size2),
    batch_size=val_batchsize,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False)

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
              metrics=['acc'])

# Train the model
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples/train_generator.batch_size,
    epochs=30,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=validation_generator.samples/validation_generator.batch_size,
    verbose=1)
```

The issue is that when I run my script to train the model, it works fine until the actual training begins. Here, it gets stuck at epoch 1/30.

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
vgg16 (Model)                (None, 15, 20, 512)       14714688
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 153600)            0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              157287424
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 1024)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 5125
=================================================================
Total params: 172,007,237
Trainable params: 164,371,973
Non-trainable params: 7,635,264
_________________________________________________________________
Found 1989 images belonging to 5 classes.
Found 819 images belonging to 5 classes.
Epoch 1/30
```

This is no good unfortunately. I looked around online and I believe that the problem is in using fit_generator. There's something about the code for fit_generator in Keras being buggy. However, most of the other people experiencing issues with the epochs end up getting stuck on later epochs (ex. somebody wants to run it for 20 epochs and it halts on epoch 19/20).

How would I go about fixing this issue? This is my first time doing deep learning so I'm incredibly confused and would appreciate any help. Do I just need to move to using model.fit()?

Comment: round() or int()  `steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples/train_generator.batch_size` and `validation_generator.samples/validation_generator.batch_size`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass a valid **integer** number to `fit_generator()` as `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` parameters.
So you can use as follows:

```
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples//train_generator.batch_size,
    epochs=30,
    validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=validation_generator.samples//validation_generator.batch_size,
    verbose=1)
```

The second factor I can see that your model has `165M` trainable **parameter** which has huge memory consumption particularly coupled with a high **batchsize**. 
You should use images with lower resolution, note that in many case we can get better results with them.

Comment: I tried doing that but it didn’t work unfortunately. Might the issue be with train_generator?

Comment: @sjgandhi2312 I don't think the issue is the traingenerator, as I worked with it a lot with no problem. If you give me all the minimum access some test data and all modules you use here, I will solve the puzzle, if you want.

Comment: That would be fantastic! How should I send you the code and the data?

Comment: @sjgandhi2312 There are a lot of cloud possibilities, like google drive, github, dropbox etc. and others and you can share it via a link with me.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VlAPPBV682ieLVQOTa7yMwHMxf_pdz2B

This link contains a readme, a training script for the CNN, and some test data. Basically, I'm trying to detect if the person is looking left, right, up, center, or has closed their eyes, so 5 classes.

Comment: Lmk if the link is broken/it looks like I’m missing a file.

Comment: @sjgandhi2312 OK I check it and will be back soon.

Comment: @sjgandhi2312 See my updated answer. Probably your model getting stuck, because of memory overflow. In my case with GTX980 4GB it works only I use 1/2 size images of the originals and with 50 batchsize. I ran the training and did all the 30 epochs with success.

Comment: Awesome! Gave it a try and it worked. It makes sense given that most Keras examples I saw are working with pretty small images

Answer (score 2):

i have the same issue and resolve it after setting validation_steps=validation_size//batch_size

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Colab. I looked at the runtime logs and it said e.g.: "Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 1195 of 5000".

So for me it was just because the shuffle buffer size was too big and it took ages to load the data into the memory.